# I have made a 3d model in blender and want to use that in android application project?

Tags: android, blender, arcore

While saving it is saved in .blend file type, Is there any possibility to export models created in Blender 3D so that I can use it in ARcore android application android studio requires .obj file to use in ARcore.
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/import-assets#import_a_3d_asset

Comment: You should find the Wavefront (.obj) export option in `File->Export`. Blender includes many import/export addons, some need to be enabled. Look in the addons list in preferences if it is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question as most likely I will search in the future, so this is my answer to your question.

Yes, you can, but it will not thoroughly read the specific Blender texture you made. The Ducky 3D channel explains ([Setting Up Your Models for AR in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSzbIWo1UWk)) this in his video as follows:

1. Export the model in '.glb' file format, you have it in the export options
2. File size: social media (4MB), and web (10MB - 20MB)
3. Check your file size: Dense models, Image resolution, animation time, amount of models

During this writing, Blender has a 3.5 LTS version.